# How to search for common elements in 2 arrays of a vector which is a key in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, c++11

I have a map which takes in a `vector<int>` of size 3 as the key and a string as value. This map contains about 2000 entries which are parsed from a file. I need to check if each element in vector 1 is present in vector 2.

```
int index;
map<vector<int>,string>::iterator i2;

for ( i2=my_map.begin() ; i2 != my_map.end(); i2++)
{
    int id_cnt = (*i2).first.at(0);
    int prev_cnt = (*i2).first.at(1);

    for (index=0; index < my_map.size(); index++)
    {
        if (prev_cnt==id_cnt[index])                     //error
        {
            //code to do something
        }
    }

    cout << "hi" <<endl;
    cout << (*i2).second << endl;
}
```

The error i get is:

> "Susbscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector.

I've been working on C++ only since a week and I don't understand anything! :(

Edit:

I have 4 columns:

```
4 6 65 gdsg
6 1 64 sggg
1 2 34 wetw
7 4 25 wtwt
8 5 25 heyq
5 7 23 fheh
2 5 12 fetd
```

I have to check if each number from the 1st column is present in column 2. So, in the case of the 1st element of column 1: 4 is present in column 2. Now I take the corresponding 3rd column number (25) and place it in a vector of 26 alphabets under the 20th element. 20th because I need to get the last character of the corresponding string (wtwt). T is the 20th letter.

I have to do this process for elements in column 1.

Comment: The value you're trying to subscript is an `int`.

Comment: Do you want to test if two vectors are equal or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: If this is your first week in C++, all of this would be considerably over your head.  Forget the C++ source code you are showing us or even the problem as stated (which has a distinct C++ bent).  Instead explain the problem you are trying to solve in English.

Comment: @Xeo: I want to test whether each value in vector 1 is present in vector 2 or not.

Comment: what 2 vectors do you want to compare? your loop goes through my_map, in which each element has a vector, but there's no _other_ vector to compare against. Also, a vector as a map key is a bad idea.

Comment: @Dave: I edited my question to show exactly what needs to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit I suggest you change your data structure to something like this:

```
struct Entry {
  int next;
  int index;
  string text;
};

typedef map<int, Entry> MyMap;

for(MyMap::iterator i = my_map.begin(); i < my_map.end(); ++i) {
  MyMap::iterator next = my_map.find(i->second.next);
  if(next == my_map.end()) {
    // not found!
    break;
  }
}
```

Your first column goes in next, your third column goes in index. The second column is the map key.

Comment: wow okay that makes sense. i'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: i don't seem to understand the if statement. if each element of the first column is equal to the last map entry, then it's not found?

Comment: @sumrania `my_map.end()` is not the last map entry, it's an iterator past the last entry and it's what `find` returns if the entry is not found. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: thank you SO much!! I learnt so many new things today because of your help! This part worked and now I'm completing the rest of the code. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to pass the comparison function as well when defining the map.

Please look at the definition of map

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/

Comment: I would maybe start with choosing appropriate data structure. Honestly map<vector<int>, string> is bizarre..